# Métodos A* y Best First Search en grafo de ciudades

Tags: python, algoritmos

Tengo un grafo de ciudades que cargo desde un archivo `.txt` y con el siguiente `for` lo cargo a `python`:

```
# Grafo principal
grafo_principal = {}

# Lee el archivo .txt y carga el grafo_principal
with open('mapa.txt', 'r') as f:
    for l in f:
        ciudad_a, ciudad_b, costo = l.split()
        if ciudad_a not in grafo_principal:
            grafo_principal[ciudad_a] = {}
        grafo_principal[ciudad_a][ciudad_b] = int(costo)
        if ciudad_b not in grafo_principal:
            grafo_principal[ciudad_b] = {}
        grafo_principal[ciudad_b][ciudad_a] = int(costo)
```

El contenido del `.txt` es el siguiente:

```
Guadalajara Veracruz 71
Guadalajara Mexico 151
Veracruz Guanajuato 75
Guanajuato Mexico 140
Guanajuato Sonora 118
Sonora Oaxaca 111
Oaxaca Tijuana 70
Tijuana QuintanaRoo 75
QuintanaRoo Mazatlan 120
Mexico Colima 80
Mexico Uruapan 99
Colima Monterrey 97
Colima Mazatlan 146
Mazatlan Monterrey 138
Monterrey Sinaloa 101
Uruapan Sinaloa 211
Sinaloa Merida 85
Merida Tepic 98
Merida Aguascalientes 142
Tepic Durango 86
Aguascalientes Acapulco 92
Leon Acapulco 87
Sinaloa Saltillo 90
```

Me dejaron trabajar con los siguiente algoritmos de búsqueda:

- Profundidad(Depth First Search)
- Amplitud(Breadth First Search)
- Profundidad Iterativa(Iterative Deepening Search)
- A-Star(A*)
- Primero el mejor(Best First Search)

Lleve acabo la implementación de los primeros 3 algoritmos de la siguiente manera:

```
# Breadth First Search Method (Busqueda en Amplitud)
def BreadthFirstSearch(grafo, inicio, destino):
    cola = [(inicio, [inicio], 0)]
    visitado = {inicio}
    while cola:
        (node, camino, costo) = cola.pop(0)
        for temp in grafo[node].keys():
            if temp == destino:
                return camino + [temp], costo + grafo[node][temp]
            else:
                if temp not in visitado:
                    visitado.add(temp)
                    cola.append((temp, camino + [temp], costo + grafo[node][temp]))


# Depth First Search Method (Busqueda en Profundidad)
def DepthFirstSearch(grafo, inicio, destino):
    pila = [(inicio, [inicio], 0)]
    visitado = {inicio}
    while pila:
        (node, camino, costo) = pila.pop()
        for temp in grafo[node].keys():
            if temp == destino:
                return camino + [temp], costo + grafo[node][temp]
            else:
                if temp not in visitado:
                    visitado.add(temp)
                    pila.append((temp, camino + [temp], costo + grafo[node][temp]))


# Iterative Deepening Search Method (Busqueda en Profundidad Iterativa)
def IterativeDeepening(grafo, inicio, destino):
    nivel = 0
    contador = 0
    pila = [(inicio, [inicio], 0)]
    visitado = {inicio}
    while True:
        nivel += 1
        while pila:
            if contador <= nivel:
                contador = 0
                (node, camino, costo) = pila.pop()
                for temp in grafo[node].keys():
                    if temp == destino:
                        return camino + [temp], costo + grafo[node][temp]
                    else:
                        if temp not in visitado:
                            visitado.add(temp)
                            contador += 1
                            pila.append((temp, camino + [temp], costo + grafo[node][temp]))
            else:
                q = pila
                visitado_bfs = {inicio}
                while q:
                    (node, camino, costo) = q.pop(0)
                    for temp in grafo[node].keys():
                        if temp == destino:
                            return camino + [temp], costo + grafo[node][temp]
                        else:
                            if temp not in visitado_bfs:
                                visitado_bfs.add(temp)
                                q.append((temp, camino + [temp], costo + grafo[node][temp]))
                break
```

Los algoritmos trabajan sin problema alguno. El problema surge con los métodos `A*` y `Best First Search` que al investigar sobre ellos, vi que por ejemplo, el `A*` lo implementaban con una cola de prioridad y al hacer bastantes intentos no conseguí absolutamente nada, ni siquiera el saber bien su funcionamiento ya que se utiliza la heuristica.

No pido que me hagan el trabajo, solo que me orienten en como lo pudiera implementar dentro del ejercicio que estoy realizando, ya que no eh conseguido éxito con todas las pruebas que he hecho.

Este es mi código completo:

```
import pprint
import os

# Pprint para mostrar de forma Pretty
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

# Grafo principal
grafo_principal = {}

# Lee el archivo .txt y carga el grafo_principal
with open('mapa.txt', 'r') as f:
    for l in f:
        ciudad_a, ciudad_b, costo = l.split()
        if ciudad_a not in grafo_principal:
            grafo_principal[ciudad_a] = {}
        grafo_principal[ciudad_a][ciudad_b] = int(costo)
        if ciudad_b not in grafo_principal:
            grafo_principal[ciudad_b] = {}
        grafo_principal[ciudad_b][ciudad_a] = int(costo)


# Breadth First Search Method (Busqueda en Amplitud)
def BreadthFirstSearch(grafo, inicio, destino):
    cola = [(inicio, [inicio], 0)]
    visitado = {inicio}
    while cola:
        (node, camino, costo) = cola.pop(0)
        for temp in grafo[node].keys():
            if temp == destino:
                return camino + [temp], costo + grafo[node][temp]
            else:
                if temp not in visitado:
                    visitado.add(temp)
                    cola.append((temp, camino + [temp], costo + grafo[node][temp]))


# Depth First Search Method (Busqueda en Profundidad)
def DepthFirstSearch(grafo, inicio, destino):
    pila = [(inicio, [inicio], 0)]
    visitado = {inicio}
    while pila:
        (node, camino, costo) = pila.pop()
        for temp in grafo[node].keys():
            if temp == destino:
                return camino + [temp], costo + grafo[node][temp]
            else:
                if temp not in visitado:
                    visitado.add(temp)
                    pila.append((temp, camino + [temp], costo + grafo[node][temp]))


# Iterative Deepening Search Method (Busqueda en Profundidad Iterativa)
def IterativeDeepening(grafo, inicio, destino):
    nivel = 0
    contador = 0
    pila = [(inicio, [inicio], 0)]
    visitado = {inicio}
    while True:
        nivel += 1
        while pila:
            if contador <= nivel:
                contador = 0
                (node, camino, costo) = pila.pop()
                for temp in grafo[node].keys():
                    if temp == destino:
                        return camino + [temp], costo + grafo[node][temp]
                    else:
                        if temp not in visitado:
                            visitado.add(temp)
                            contador += 1
                            pila.append((temp, camino + [temp], costo + grafo[node][temp]))
            else:
                q = pila
                visitado_bfs = {inicio}
                while q:
                    (node, camino, costo) = q.pop(0)
                    for temp in grafo[node].keys():
                        if temp == destino:
                            return camino + [temp], costo + grafo[node][temp]
                        else:
                            if temp not in visitado_bfs:
                                visitado_bfs.add(temp)
                                q.append((temp, camino + [temp], costo + grafo[node][temp]))
                break

# A-Star Search Method (Busqueda A-Estrella)
def a_star_search(grafo, inicio, destino):
    #Metodo

# Best First search (Busqueda Primero el Mejor)
def best_first_search(grafo, inicio, destino):
    #Metodo

n = 1
while n == 1:
    os.system("CLS")
    print("""============================================
                Grafo Completo
============================================""")
    pp.pprint(grafo_principal)
    print("""============================================
[1] Amplitud
[2] Profundidad
[3] Profundidad Iterativa
[4] A Star
[5] Primero el mejor
[0] Salir
============================================""")
    x = input("Opcion: ")
    if x == '1':
        inicio = input("Ingresa el Inicio: ")
        while inicio not in grafo_principal:
            print("Ciudad no encontrada intenta nuevamente")
            inicio = input("Ingresa el Inicio: ")
        destino = input("Ingresa el Destino: ")
        while destino not in grafo_principal:
            print("Ciudad no encontrada intenta nuevamente")
            destino = input("Ingresa el Destino: ")
        print("""============================================
                 Resultados
============================================""")
        print (BreadthFirstSearch(grafo_principal, inicio, destino))
        print("============================================")
        os.system("pause")

    elif x == '2':
        inicio = input("Ingresa el Inicio: ")
        while inicio not in grafo_principal:
            print("Ciudad no encontrada intenta nuevamente")
            inicio = input("Ingresa el Inicio: ")
        destino = input("Ingresa el Destino: ")
        while destino not in grafo_principal:
            print("Ciudad no encontrada intenta nuevamente")
            destino = input("Ingresa el Destino: ")
        print("""============================================
                 Resultados
============================================""")
        print (DepthFirstSearch(grafo_principal, inicio, destino))
        print("============================================")
        os.system("pause")

    elif x == '3':
        inicio = input("Ingresa el Inicio: ")
        while inicio not in grafo_principal:
            print("Ciudad no encontrada intenta nuevamente")
            inicio = input("Ingresa el Inicio: ")
        destino = input("Ingresa el Destino: ")
        while destino not in grafo_principal:
            print("Ciudad no encontrada intenta nuevamente")
            destino = input("Ingresa el Destino: ")
        print("""============================================
                 Resultados
============================================""")
        print (IterativeDeepening(grafo_principal, inicio, destino))
        print("============================================")
        os.system("pause")

    elif x == '4':
        inicio = input("Ingresa el Inicio: ")
        while inicio not in grafo_principal:
            print("Ciudad no encontrada intenta nuevamente")
            inicio = input("Ingresa el Inicio: ")
        destino = input("Ingresa el Destino: ")
        while destino not in grafo_principal:
            print("Ciudad no encontrada intenta nuevamente")
            destino = input("Ingresa el Destino: ")
        print("""============================================
                 Resultados
============================================""")
        print(a_star_search(grafo_principal, inicio, destino))
        print("============================================")
        os.system("pause")

    elif x == '5':
        inicio = input("Ingresa el Inicio: ")
        while inicio not in grafo_principal:
            print("Ciudad no encontrada intenta nuevamente")
            inicio = input("Ingresa el Inicio: ")
        destino = input("Ingresa el Destino: ")
        while destino not in grafo_principal:
            print("Ciudad no encontrada intenta nuevamente")
            destino = input("Ingresa el Destino: ")
        print("""============================================
                 Resultados
============================================""")
        print(best_first_search(grafo_principal, inicio, destino))
        print("============================================")
        os.system("pause")

    elif x == '0':
        break
```

Y se utiliza de la siguiente manera:

1. Se despliega el menú principal con el grafo cargado:

[image: Menu Principal]

2. Seleccionamos el algoritmo y ingresamos de que ciudad a que ciudad queremos ir y el programa nos arroja el costo total y las ciudades visitadas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas, he encontrado esto, a ver si te sirve de ayuda https://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/implementation.html

Comment: cual es tu pregunta? no entiendo del todo

Comment: @x-rw tal cual lo puse hay en la publicación, solo es orientación de como funciona el algoritmo y en este caso como puedo implementarlo en lo que estoy haciendo.

Comment: Para hacer el algoritmo `A*` necesitas la distancia en linea recta que hay desde un punto hasta otro, es decir, la `distancia euclídea`. En función de este dato ya puedes calcularlo con la función de evaluación `f(x) = g(x) + h(x)`, donde `g(x)` es el coste de ir desde el inicio hasta el punto actual y `h(x)` es la distancia euclídea desde el punto actual hasta el destino. Sin ese dato (que yo sepa) no se puede realizar el algoritmo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Primero me gustaría definir algunos conceptos generales para usar en la respuesta:

- **Estado**: representación finita del dominio para un momento dado, expresada en algún formalismo (puede considerarse como los nodos de un grafo).
- **Estado inicial**: el estado desde donde se comienza a resolver el problema de búsqueda.
- **Operador**: función para transformar un estado en otro, es decir, pasar de un estado a otro.
- **Estado alcanzable**: es un estado al cual se puede llegar desde el estado inicial aplicando una secuencia de operadores.
- **Espacio de búsqueda o espacio de estados**: es el conjunto de todos los estados alcanzables desde el estado inicial.
- **Frontera**: es la colección de estados que se pueden visitar (habitualmente almacenados en forma de pila, cola, lista...)en un momento dado.

Ahora, los métodos de búsqueda que ya tenés desarrollados, se conocen como métodos de búsqueda **ciegos**, ya que simplemente exprolan el espacio de búsqueda hasta que se "tropiezan" con la meta. Estos métodos no toman en consideración la información sobre cual nodo en la frontera puede ser "más prometedor" para alcanzar la meta.

Por otro lado, los métodos de búsqueda **A *** y **Best First Search** se clasifican como métodos de búsqueda **informados**. Esto quiere decir que utilizan la información presente en los estados para realizar una estimación de cual nodo en la frontera puede ser más promisorio para llegar más rápidamente a una meta. Esta información llamada **heurística** es particular al dominio de aplicación en el que se realiza la búsqueda. Para un nodo N, se representa esa información heurística, con una función llamada `h(N)` que retorna un valor no negativo. El valor de `h(N)` es una **estimación** del costo del camino menos costoso entre N y una meta alcanzable desde N. En general, cada problema tiene su propia `h(N)`.

**Método de búsqueda informada Best First Search (El mejor primero)**

La estrategia consiste en elegir de la frontera el de menor `h(N)`, esto es, el que "parece estar más cerca de la meta". Para este caso, se puede implementar la frontera como una **cola con prioridad**, ordenada ascendentemente por `h(N)`. De esta forma, Best First Search funciona como Profundidad(Depth First Search), lo que significa que se estaría tomando el primer elemento de esa frontera (que es el de menor valor `h(N)`, o sea, el mejor primero).

Ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

NOTA: para cada nodo N se muestra a un costado el valor de `h(N)`.

En este ejemplo, y con esa heurística **BFS** encuentra la meta m1 (la cual no es la óptima)

**Método de búsqueda informada A***

Para explicar este método, necesitamos definir un nuevo concepto: la **función de costo de camino**.

- Una función de costo de camino para el nodo N, `g(N)`, es la función que determina el costo para llegar del estado inicial a otro estado N.

Recordemos que `h(N)` es una estimación del costo del camino menos costoso entre N y una meta alcanzable desde N.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

NOTA: el valor en el arco entre dos nodos es el costo de llegar de un nodo al otro.

La estrategia del método A* es elegir de la frontera el nodo de menor **`f(N) = g(N) + h(N)`**:

Ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A* considera tanto la información real `g(N)` como la estimación `h(N)`.

-`f(N) = g(N) + h(N)`

- `f(b) = 20 + 2 = 22`
- `f(c) = 10 + 4 = 14`

De esta manera encuentra la meta m2 (óptima), ya que se eligió el nodo c para comenzar (el de menor `f(N)`).

Para una descripción más formal de estos métodos, recomiendo: 
*Poole, D., Mackworth, A., and Goebel, R. Computational Intelligence: A Logical Approach. 4.5: Heuristic } Search*

/----------------------/

Ahora, para tu problema en particular (considerando que N representa una ciudad del grafo, es decir, un nodo del mismo), y con la información que tenés, es necesario definir esa función heurística (`h(N)`) para poder aplicar estos métodos de búsqueda. La única función herística que se me ocurre es la distancia entre dos ciudades, es decir, primero tenés que tener los puntos de cada ciudad (Latitud, Longitud) y al momento de calcular `f(N) = g(N) + h(N)`, primero obtienes `h(N)` calculando la distancia entre los puntos de la ciudad que representa el nodo N y el punto que representa la ciudad **destino**. La distancia la podés calcular así:

```
-dist = sqrt( (x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2 )
```

(La forma de calcular la distancia en python lo respondieron [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5228392/3239070)).

Es decir, primero podrías obtener los puntos (Latitud, Longitud) de cada ciudad y guardarlos en el archivo `.txt` (estos datos puedes obtenerlos de aquí: [Buscar o introducir la latitud y longitud - Sección Obtener las coordenadas de un sitio](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/18539?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=es)):

```
Guadalajara Veracruz 71
Guadalajara Mexico 151
Veracruz Guanajuato 75
.
.
.


Guadalajara (Latitud, Longitud)
Veracruz (Latitud, Longitud)
.
.
.
```

Luego, al momento de buscar en el grafo calculás `f(N)` en base a `g(N)`(este dato ya lo tenés, porque es la suma de las distancias recorridas desde la ciudad **origen** hasta la ciudad N) y `h(N)`(aquí calculás la distancia entre la ciudad N y la ciudad **destino**) y **eliges** el nodo que menor valor `f(N)` tenga. Así continúas hasta encontrar el nodo N que representa la ciudad 'destino'.

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es importante remarcar que:

Si la solución existe, A* siempre encontrará una solución y además la primera solución encontrada será optimal, si las siguientes condiciones se verfician:

- el factor de ramificación es finito(es decir, cada nodo tiene una cantidad finita de vecinos).
- El costo de los arcos es estrictamente positivo y
- `h(N)` es una cota inferior de mínimo costo del paso más corto desde el nodo N a un nodo meta.

Perdón por lo longitud de la respuesta, pero es un tema un poco extenso.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, se que es un tema bastante amplio pero gracias a tu explicación me quedo bastante claro todo el tema, en especial la heuristica y como aplicarla en este proyecto.